# Get-params documentation with Flask-Autodoc

Tags: python, flask, autodoc

I have an api method, which takes 2 GET-params. Can I generate documentation using [Flask-Autodoc](https://github.com/acoomans/flask-autodoc) for these arguments like it works for variables in the routes?

For example:

```
@auto.doc()
@app.route('/rss_filter')
def rssFilter():
    '''Filter rss-feed items by given words'''

    url = request.args.get('url')
    words = request.args.get('words').split(',')

    # Doing something ...
```

I want to see documentation for this function like this:

> **/rss_filter**
>   Methods: HEAD, GET, OPTIONS
>   Arguments: *url* - Feed url, *words* - List of words separated by comma
>   Description: Filter rss-feed items by given words